# is it good to have side effect from filter method's callback

Tags: javascript, arrays

when reading colleague's code , I surprised to see filter's callback have side effect as follows.

```
let output = [];
let input = ['apple', 'boy', 'carrot'];
input.filter(w => output.push(w + '_suffix'));
console.log(output);
//log:-
//["apple_suffix", "boy_suffix", "carrot_suffix"]
```

I suggested to use `map()` method . But I haven't thought about the array methods in this way. i.e. affecting state outside of callback function. I found lot of other colleagues used map method also in similar way.

Is it ok to use array methods in this way ? If no, how to enforce that in team ? Typescript also not helping to enforce. I guess linting also cannot be used.

Comment: It is not efficient because `filter` and `map` will do extract jobs to return a new array and I think it is more like less readable as the intention of filter and map is supposed to return a new array you want.

Comment: This should either be a map() directly assigning to output, or a forEach pushing to the output array. You can lint for [array-callback-return](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return) set to `"allowImplicit": false`, or in conjunction with [arrow-body-style](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style) 'always'. This won't completely solve the problem, but it will point out when an unneccesary return is being used.